# how to display output text fields in 2 columns in visualforce

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="Apartment__c" showHeader="false" renderAs="pdf" DocType="html" standardStylesheets="false">
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock title="Appartment Details">
           <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" columns="2" >
         <table style="width:100%">   
         <tr> 
         <td> <apex:outputField value="{! Apartment__c.Name }" /> </td> 
         </tr> 
          <tr> 
          <td> <apex:outputField value="{! Apartment__c.Floor_No__c }"/> </td>
           </tr> 
            <tr> 
          <td> <apex:outputField value="{! Apartment__c.Phase__c }" /> </td>
           </tr> 
            <tr> 
         <td> <apex:outputField value="{! Apartment__c.Property_No__c }"/> </td>
          </tr> 
           <tr> 
         <td> <apex:outputField value="{! Apartment__c.Facing__c }" /> </td>
          </tr> 
           <tr> 
          <td> <apex:outputField value="{! Apartment__c.Terrace_Area_Cost__c }"/> </td>
          </tr> 
    </table>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>  
         </apex:pageBlock>           
    <apex:pageBlock title="Cost Breakup">
           <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" columns="1" >
         <table style="width:100%">   
         <tr> 
         <td> <apex:outputField value="{! Apartment__c.Appox_Amount__c }" /> </td> 
         </tr> 
          <tr> 
          <td> <apex:outputField value="{! Apartment__c.Basic_Rate_Per_Sqft__c }"/> </td>
           </tr>
           <tr> 
          <td> <apex:outputField value="{! Apartment__c.SFT__c }"/> </td>
           </tr> 
           <tr> 
          <td> <apex:outputField value="{! Apartment__c.Floor_Rise_Charges_Per_Sqft__c }"/> </td>
           </tr>
           <tr> 
          <td> <apex:outputField value="{! Apartment__c.Total_Rate__c }"/> </td>
           </tr>
            <tr> 
          <td> <apex:outputField value="{! Apartment__c.Layout__c }"/> </td>
           </tr>             
          </table>                 
           </apex:pageBlockSection>         
         </apex:pageBlock>    
         </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pns6QAA    - this is the original question posted, still i have not got the answer

Comment: Why are you displaying a table within a pageBlockSection?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use table with `apex:pageBlockSection`. It will automatically set in two columns as set by `columns` attribute.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection  collapsible="false" columns="2">
    <apex:outputField value="{! Apartment__c.Name }" /> 
    <apex:outputField value="{! Apartment__c.Floor_No__c }"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{! Apartment__c.Phase__c }" /> 
    <apex:outputField value="{! Apartment__c.Property_No__c }"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{! Apartment__c.Facing__c }" />
    <apex:outputField value="{! Apartment__c.Terrace_Area_Cost__c }"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockSection.htm)